# cmd doesn't recognize -O optimization

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

in my command prompt i am trying to run my python310 interpreter,
but with no succes when i try to run it with optimization -O.
Even when, after i am  importing with succes, the py file, and is printing the str "Modules executed with python -O"have **debug** set to False.
What am i doing wrong? I just started with coding, its a bit frustrating. Will appreciate any feedback.
I cannot find unfortunately anything after i troubleshot in google. Maybe my question doesn't make sense?
My module ends with:
try:
py_compile.compile(**file**, **file** +'c')
py_compile.compile(**file**, **file**+'o')

Comment: What is the purpose of this? If you have just started with coding, it's not clear why cou care about optimization or compilation of Python source files.

Comment: Its in an exercise on a lesson about exceptation. As i said i am still learning and somethings feel forced. I just don't know why cmd promt is not recognising -O.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen if `-O` is recognized? You need to post code that we can copy, paste and run. Please read [mcve].